# Gitlab project based on template members empty

Tags: gitlab

I created a gitlab project and I configured it as [gitlab project instance-level templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/custom_project_templates.html).

In this project, I configured as member 5 persons and 1 group (`Settings` > `Members`) .

When I create a project based on this template, the existing members and groups are empty in the new project (like not imported from the template)

Other configuration like branches, default branch, `README.md` are correctly imported from the template.

Is there a missing feature from gitlab or am I doing something wrong ?

Gitlab version : `12.3.0-ee`

Comment: not exactly the same issue, but probably related: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/30437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received an answer from Gitlab support. When creating a project from an Instance template, the imported settings are only :

- Project and wiki repositories
- Project uploads
- Project configuration, including services
- Issues with comments, merge requests with diffs and comments, labels, milestones, snippets, and other project entities
- Design Management files and data
- LFS objects
- Issue boards

More info in the [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/import_export.html#exported-contents). They created an [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/34046) to include members when creating project template.